# Besides data races and deadlocks, are there any other problems to focus on when multithreading?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have the following very poorly written, but working, code.
It was compiled with mingw-w64 on Windows 7 64-bit, and runs on a i3-6100U CPU.

```cpp
//g++ -g -std=c++17 -Wall Test.cpp -lmingw32 -o Test

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

long long int val = 1;

void thread1(){
    for(int i=0; i < 1000; i++){
        val = -val;
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }
}

void thread2(){
    for(int i=0; i < 100; i++){
        val = -val;
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    std::thread t1 (thread1);
    std::thread t2 (thread2);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I have read that threads don't share the stack data. Is val not on the stack?
Shouldn't val's type also have to be wrapped in a std::atomic?
I tested with gdb to make sure two separate threads are actually made and running.
Shouldn't simultaneous writing and reading make something malfunction?

Comment: Your code does not "work".  It might compile, run, and give you the correct result but it has a data race so it has undefined behavior.

Comment: You have to protect access to val, either by mutex or by atomic. ` Is val not on the stack?` No, it is not

Comment: Okay I should have remembered global variables are in the data segment, so both threads do share the same address for val in memory.

Comment: "Besides data races and deadlocks, are there any other problems to focus on when multithreading?" - Yes. *Many*. Examples: Priority inversion. Live locks. False sharing. And much, much more.